# Nullable Integer ? (working with linq)

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, nemerle

I've got exception about convert NULL to Int32.

I've got a table from database with nullable tinyint

```
[Column(Storage="_StatType", DbType="tinyint NULL")]
public StatType : int { get { _StatType; } }
```

(to get C# code just replace variable's type)

and after making linq select

```
def StartLinq = linq <#from lpi in _CfgListParIzm
    where lpi.ID_ListParIzm==drr1
    select (lpi.StatType)
#> ;
```

`StartLinq.ToArray()[0]` can't be readed if that is null :-/

```
mutable STT : int = 0;
try
{
    _=int.TryParse(StartLinq.ToArray()[0].ToString(), out STT);
}
catch { | _ is Exception => () /* I don't care*/ }
```

upper code is very poor trick :( I wont use it.

Comment: Why is this question tagged C#?

Comment: the question is about null-able integer. and I don't hope to get Nemerle answer. But maybe I do wrong :-/

Comment: @Peter - it is sort of C#. It's also mixed with nemerle http://nemerle.org/

Comment: Nullable types is not C# specific, its a feature of the .Net Framework.  Ohwell, seems @nCdy got it right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know nemerle, but in C# you would make StatType a nullable integer (`Nullable<int>` aka `int?`) instead of a non-nullable one. That's the most logical solution - does nemerle support nullable value types?